# Could you bake matzah during Passover?

Tags: halacha, passover, matzah

This is a theoretical question, I have no plans to bake my own Matza.

But could you get flour and make Kosher Matza DURING Pessah (any time during the whole week)? Is there a law against it, if it's for the needs of the holiday?
Is there a law not to "own" raw flour? Or any other reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is permissible, but you have to be extra careful how you handle stray pieces of dough or leftovers in the kneading trough which might become Chametz (see ShA OC 459:4 and 460:3 for details).

Comment: They did it in the gemara as a normal thing. But the custom for hundreds of years is not to do it because if there are any problems with the flour, bitul works better before Pesach than on Pesach. The custom now is to bake all matzah before Pesach.

Comment: @MichoelR some communities practice that stringency but not all do.

Comment: Ah. Who doesn't? I think I saw this in the Shulchan Aruch Harav and the MIshnah Berurah.

Comment: Broadly speaking, communities who eat soft matza. If you made that in advance it'd be stale.