How to make matzo using a pizza maker, while ensuring that it stays kosher for Passover?
In preparation for next year, I would like to have fresh soft matzo every day (except Shabbat / Yom Tov of course). I recently heard of the concept of an electric pizza maker. It is basically 2 heated trays of metal that cover the dough from above and below.

To do this I will need to buy kosher for Passover flour, and make sure that the entire process is less than 18 minutes. However, what care needs to be taken so that the pizza cooker stays kosher for Passover? I won't use the device throughout the year, it will be with my Passover supplies. However, is there any issue that dough was in the device and then after I took out the matzo, some crumbs remained, and after 18 minutes turned into Chametz?
There are two issues that I can think of,

How can I make sure not to make Chametz on Passover?
After cooking, does the fact that the device cooks crumbs for longer than 18 minutes, cause the device to be not Kosher for Passover?


Crumbs that are baked that stay in the oven are not a problem. That's just matza meal and doesn't become chametz with further cooking.

Making matza is a skill that average Jews excelled at for millenia. Find a person who knows it to teach you and you'll be fine (eg. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/137598/making-matzah-at-home?rq=1#comment458807_137598). Don't learn from reading blogs.

I have almost a year to prepare myself. I'm right now at the "check the internet if it's even a possibility" stage.

@DoubleAA "Matza meal" that is funny. Is this how it is called in the US? Comes from the German/Yiddish matza-mehl which is matza-flour (mehl is flour in German)

@mbloch https://www.amazon.com/Streits-Matzo-Meal/dp/B0083KUYK0 but "meal" also means [usually course-] flour in English, see definition 2 https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meal

You would need mayim shelanu. You would need to make sure no dough from the kneading got left anywhere in the kitchen or utensils, as it could rise and create chametz.  You would be better off using matzah meal if you eat gebrochts.

@N.T. Mayim shelanu is so easy to get that the fact that you would think to bring it up as an impediment shows you aren't trying to present a realistic picture of the difficulty.

@N.T. that's exactly my concern. If I knead the dough on a plate, does that have to be cleaned completely before the 18 minutes are up? Why does the oven not need to be? Is it because it is hot enough to burn the crumbs?

@HanMah In principle you can declare the dough residue in the bowl null before it becomes chametz and then just throw it out and do your next batch on another clean disposable bowl, but most nowadays try to bake everything before pesach to avoid complications https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70732/759

@DoubleAA I want to make fresh soft matzah. So that will have to be made during Passover. But thank you for all of the pointers that I should look out for. I will definitely talk to my Rabbi and verify my setup before I start.

@DoubleAA I didn't say it was difficult. I said he would need it.

@N.T., wouldn't that make the resulting product mezonot ? This kind of defeats the purpose of having freshly baked matzah

There's a lot of misconceptions here so I'll try and lay out the facts. As of now I will leave my answer unsourced. As others know I tend to edit my answers a lot to bring in the sources later.

The entire process does not need to be done in 18 minutes. You have 18 minutes from the moment you stop kneading the dough to put that matzah in the oven/hot cooking surface. Ideally you should not wait those 18 minutes but start baking as soon as you are done kneading.

The material of the cooking surfaces of your pizza maker is very important for this discussion. Some materials can't be kashered, so if you accidentally make hameitz one time you may not ever be able to use that pizza oven for matzah again. But if it's made of a material that can be kashered then you don't have to worry.

One should practice extensively BEFORE Pesah. That way you have all the answers and problems worked out. In terms of crumbs, as long as they are cooked they are not and will never be chameitz. But ideally one should measure out the dough so there are no crumbs. Personally I try and grind my own whole wheat flour because the flour is way cleaner to deal with (it's heavier so it doesn't fly all over the place) and it makes less crumbs. But it definitely makes less "fluffy" matzah.

I don't know if you can get Kasher l'Fesah flour all year long, but if you can kasher the pizza maker then again I'd practice with regular flour (which is allowed by the S'A anyways) and then Kasher your Pizza Maker before Pesah

As @DoubleAA has mentioned, I would not try and learn just from reading sources. At the end of the day you are making bread, there's a feel and a look to dough. If you've never made a dough before, you should learn from literally anyone how to roll dough and deal with dough. Once you've learned that, then you can rely on reading sources a bit more. There are also videos you can watch online, but they still won't give you a feel for the dough



I don't see how one can make matzos at home with a pizza maker on passover and keep to all the laws.
The issues you brought up are important.  First of all, Kosher-for-Passover matzo baking requires an especially hot oven.  There are many others details as well.   Here is one source: can we bake our own matzos (chabad)
Besides for the many potential problems in amateur matzo baking, baking matzo over the holiday is even more problematic, as even the smallest amount of chametz cannot be nullified.

-1 Pizza ovens are well known for being quite hot for fast baking.

@DoubleAA pizza ovens are indeed quite hot for fast baking. Electric countertop "pizza makers" are not the same thing as pizza ovens.

There is no minimum baking temperature for Matzah. As long as you preheat the pizza maker it should work fine

@Esther How do you answer the question of the S"A saying you make matzah on a roof tile that's being heated or even directly on warm coals themselves?
